# Word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application") Displays the opened file every other time despite Word.Visible = False command

Tags: python, win32com

I am having a terrible time getting win32com.client to cooperate.  It seemingly switches application state to "visible" and ignores my Visible = False commands.  I think this is an error in the package, but I want to see if anybody on here has any ideas first.  The bug is more annoying than anything, it causes the file referenced in my path variable to be open every other time.

The code below should opens an instance of MS Word **in the background**, then accesses the referenced file.

It currently opens a word application every other time the code is run. Ideas...?

```
import win32com.client as win32

path = 'string to my file'

Word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
Word.Visible = False
Word.Documents.Open(path)
```

Comment: What versions of everything (Python, Word, Windows)? What's in the document - does it open other documents any differently?

Comment: I was getting the same results (only working every other time). Try adding a `Word.Quit()` somewhere. This made it work every time (I think, since the window is invisible).

Comment: Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 15:00:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Microsoft Word 2013 (15.0.4841.1000) MSO (15.0.4841.1000) 32-bit

Comment: Martineau, question, where should I add the Word.Quit().  When I add that in there it doesn't solve my problem, but the way I'm doing it Word ends up getting locked open and I have to kill the app in Task Manager.

Comment: @aacealo add `word.Quit()` following the last line where the `word` object is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
word.Documents.Open(docPath)
doc = word.ActiveDocument
```

Only difference I see is an uppercase W in 'word.Visible' in your code.